# Speeding up the exporting of appliances in Virtualbox

Tags: linux, virtualbox

The export of appliances can take a long time. I want to ask you, how I can speed up the process of exporting an appliance to an external hdd without buying better hardware components. The speed increase should be achieved at the software level.

I use the current version of Virtualbox and my operating system is GNU/Linux.
The distribution is Linux Mint 18.3 with XFCE (64 Bit).

What I also found strange is the fact that by the process of exporting the appliance, the processor works very little. The first core of the processor was about 20% busy, the other 3 cores about 1%. Was the processor "too lazy", or is there a bottleneck somewhere?

Comment: If you look at the involved file sizes, the problem should be quite obvious: I/O. Nothing you can do about that. Get a faster external HDD (or even SSD), if possible with USB 3.0.

Comment: When something is slow and the processor is far from 100% used, it means the bottleneck isn't the processor. The usual suspects are disk I/O (especially on external drives), not enough RAM (inducing swapping), and network. In addition some processes can only use a single core at a time, and won't for instance use more that 25% CPU on a 4-CPU machine.